# Retry mechanism for downloading files

Tags: c#

I have created a function that find files on a FTP folder.

```
    public static List<string> GetFileList(NetworkCredential credential, string FTPSite, string FTPFolder, string extension)
    {
        string LSOutput = "";
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

            //Fetch LS
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + FTPSite + FTPFolder);
            request.Credentials = credential;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.EnableSsl = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            LSOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            PrepareLog("LS output while finding files:");
            PrepareLog(LSOutput);


        //Parse the LS
        string[] LSOutputLines = LSOutput.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string LSOutputLine in LSOutputLines)
            files.Add(LSOutputLine);

        //Filter files
        files = files.Where(f => f.ToLower().EndsWith(extension.ToLower())).ToList();

        PrepareLogAndEmail("Total " + extension.ToLower() + " files found: " + files.Count, LogMessageType.Simple);
        return files;
    }
```

Exception handling is done at the place where the function is being called.
Now the problem is that sometimes the FTP faces some issues(like timeout) and then we have to rerun the program.

I have been asked to add 3 times retry mechanism and here is what I did to retry it once.

```
    public static List<string> GetFileList(NetworkCredential credential, string FTPSite, string FTPFolder, string extension)
    {
        string LSOutput = "";
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            //Fetch LS
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + FTPSite + FTPFolder);
            request.Credentials = credential;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.EnableSsl = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            LSOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            PrepareLog("LS output while finding files:");
            PrepareLog(LSOutput);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PrepareLogAndEmail("First attempt failed: Details: " + ex.Message, LogMessageType.AttemptFailed);
            PrepareLogAndEmail("Second attempt started" + ex.Message, LogMessageType.Simple);

            //Fetch LS
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + FTPSite + FTPFolder);
            request.Credentials = credential;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.EnableSsl = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = null;
            response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            LSOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

            PrepareLog("LS output while finding files(second attempt):");
            PrepareLog(LSOutput);
        }


        //Parse the LS
        string[] LSOutputLines = LSOutput.Trim().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string LSOutputLine in LSOutputLines)
            files.Add(LSOutputLine);

        //Filter files
        files = files.Where(f => f.ToLower().EndsWith(extension.ToLower())).ToList();

        PrepareLogAndEmail("Total " + extension.ToLower() + " files found: " + files.Count, LogMessageType.Simple);
        return files;
    }
```

Now if I have to add 2 more tries, will I need to do this sort of daiys chaining or is there any other cleaner option available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a retry loop, something like below

You will notice that I make use of a bolean to flag out of a successfull download, or the retries count to terminate.

I would even go as far as changing the last section to check if the download was successfull, and notify the user if it was not, Maybe even logging the error messages.

```
    public static List<string> GetFileList(NetworkCredential credential, string FTPSite, string FTPFolder, string extension)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        int retries = 0;
        int maxRetries = 5;
        bool downloaded = false;
        string LSOutput = "";
        while (!downloaded && retries < maxRetries)
        {
            try
            {
                LSOutput = "";
                //Fetch LS
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://" + FTPSite + FTPFolder);
                request.Credentials = credential;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.EnableSsl = true;
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                FtpWebResponse response = null;
                response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                LSOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();

                PrepareLog("LS output while finding files:");
                PrepareLog(LSOutput);
                downloaded = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                retries++;
            }
        }


        if (downloaded)
        {
            //Parse the LS
            string[] LSOutputLines = LSOutput.Trim().Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string LSOutputLine in LSOutputLines)
                files.Add(LSOutputLine);

            //Filter files
            files = files.Where(f => f.ToLower().EndsWith(extension.ToLower())).ToList();

            PrepareLogAndEmail("Total " + extension.ToLower() + " files found: " + files.Count, LogMessageType.Simple);
            return files;
        }
        else
        {
            PrepareLogAndEmail("Failed to download file", LogMessageType.Simple);
            return null;
        }
    }
```